# Allow Non-admin Users to reboot Win 2008 R2 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-permissions

Is there a way to give a Non-Admin user dedicated permissions to reboot a server?

Would it work to create a "Rebooter" Group and can I assign a group policy to allow reboots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to grant the user or group the `Shut down the system` and/or `Force shutdown from a remote system` [privilege](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457125.aspx) depending on how the users will be rebooting the system.

Comment: Thanks. It gave me the right direction. I created a new group, added the user and gave the "Shut down the system" privilege. Now it works

Answer (score 2):

It should work. I thought 'Shutdown the system' user right in local(domain) security policy will be enougth. Also you can check other rights of 'Backup operators' group or even add your user to 'Server operators' group (not recommended)

But do you need to reboot server remotely or your user(s) have an access to server phisycally? In last case most simple solution IMHO it's to set up 'Shutdown server' action on 'When I press Power button' event in server's Power options.

One more way: create a scheduled task (as admin) with script which will check every minute 'semaphore' file presence and runs 'shutdown /r' command if file exist. Teach users who authorised to restart server to create such files in right place.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went with the option to create a group and add the "Shut down" privilege.

In addition, your idea with the semaphore file helped me with another problem, totally disconnected with this one - still a good idea :D

Answer (score 1):

`Start Button > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy`

Then add your user as per the steps shown below.

[image]